# How do I change the axis direction for the bones?

Tags: armature, bones, axis

I was following Royal Skies pelvis weight paint drivers video when I notice that the Z axis for the thigh bone is pointing right, and the Y axis is pointing down, but my thigh bone's axis is pointing in different directions which I think is causing technical issues. Is there a way to change the directions of the bone's axis?[image]

Answer (score 0):

Select bone, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>A</kbd>, apply rotation, profit.

Comment: I went into pose mode selected the bone I wanted, but when I pressed ctrl A I kept getting this small menu with four options.

Comment: You have to be in object mode for this.

Answer (score 0):

What you show is not the bone's axis, it's the global or local axis, the bone's axis are not the same, to see them go into *Object Data > Viewport Display* and enable the *Axis* option. or in the *Transform Orientations* panel choose *Normal*:

[image]

You can't change the bone's axis, Y will always be the bone's main axis, but you can make it rotate on itself with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> + degrees.

If you want to change the local axis, meaning the armature's axis, you can enable the *Transform Affect Only Origins* option and rotate the origin as you want:

[image]